# Is there any assert statement in python to check if there is no raise of any exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

As we know in python we use assert. Raises to check exception scenarios, like wise is there any assert Statment opposite to that? Like by taking the scenario testcase will not raise any exception.I have checked online didn't got proper answers, I am new bee to python, thanks in advance

Comment: If your code raises an unexpected exception, the test should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example, if you are using unittest for your testing there is [assertRaises()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises). If you are using pytest for your testing then there is [raises()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.raises).

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the type of exception that was raised and even the message used.

```py
def do_exception():
    raise TypeError("foo bar baz")

def test():
    try:
        do_exception()
    except Exception as exc:
        assert type(exc) == TypeError, "Type error should have been raised"
        assert exc.args[0] == "foo bar baz", "error message was incorrect"
```